# Why there is an error when using format for input

Tags: python, format

I am using f format to display results in the following code:

```
numb1 = input("Enter the first number here: ")
numb2 = input("Enter second number here: ")


print(f"Product of {numb1} and {numb2} is {numb1 * numb2}"
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Anyone has any idea to where I am getting it wrong? I researched and could not find the answer.

Thank you

Comment: You just forgot the closing `)`  on the call to `print`.

Comment: Missing ```)``` ,```print(f"Product of {numb1} and {numb2} is {numb1 * numb2})```"

Answer (score 1):

`numb1` and `numb2` are both `str`-typed ([because that's what `input` returns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)): you need to coerce them to `int` for the `*` operation to be valid inside the f-string. Strings *do* have a `__mul__` method, but (a) it's not defined for an operation against another `str` (which is what you're attempting to do here), and (b) the product of an `str` and an `int` won't give you the result you want (rather, `'a' * 5` produces the repeated character sequence, also an `str`).

Assuming the other issues in your code are a result of your formatting (e.g. missing newline or `;` between `input` statements and no closing `)` in `print`), that's exactly what the exception will tell you (a `TypeError`).

One correct approach:

```py
numb1 = input("Enter the first number here: ") 
numb2 = input("Enter second number here: ")
print(f"Product of {numb1} and {numb2} is {int(numb1) * int(numb2)}")
```

`int` truncates, so if digits to the right of the decimal point should be correctly handled in your input, you'll want to perform the coercion with `float` (assuming floating-point error is acceptable) instead.

Comment: It works! Much appreciate it, thank you